# Django and CKEditor ValueError: The joined path (C:\ckeditor\lang\en.js) is located outside of the base path component

Tags: django, ckeditor, django-cms

I am getting the following error when trying to run ckeditor from Django. Specifically Django CMS:
ValueError: The joined path (C:\ckeditor\lang\en.js) is located outside of the base path component

I have a virtual enviornment going so has anyone seen something like this before?

Answer (score 1):

Well I found a somewhat solution:
In the cms_plugins.py of

> \env\Lib\site-packages\djangocms_text_ckeditor

Line 64:

```
ckeditor_basepath = '{0}/ckeditor/'.format(settings.STATIC_URL)
```

Change that to

```
ckeditor_basepath = '{0}ckeditor/'.format(settings.STATIC_URL)
```

That fixed the problem for me. Basically it appended and extra / when trying to integrate the CKEDITOR_BASEPATH into the STATIC URL for Django CMS 3.0

Answer (score 0):

This is now fixed on Github:

https://github.com/divio/djangocms-text-ckeditor/blob/master/djangocms_text_ckeditor/cms_plugins.py#L68

but they haven't built a new release with it yet.